# How to open iOS settings from javascript web application in iOS chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

I want to redirect to the iOS general settings when clicking a button in Web application from iOS Chrome Browser.

`<a target="_blank" href="App-prefs://prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION"> Open Settings </a>`

The above block of code is working in Safari. But not in iOS Chrome. I checked a lot of forums. But they are not specifically for iOS chrome browser. Any idea on this?